# What is this paradoxical image in the site's header?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

What is this paradoxical image composed of red cubes in the site's header called? Is there something (not necesserily mathematically) interesting about it other than its only being able to be described logically using [inconsistent geometry](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-inconsistent/#GeoInc)?

I feel the need to point out that the image is paradoxical if and only if the six cubes are congruent, otherwise it is just an optical illusion. Also, [here's](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/math/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=4ec1df2e49b1&a) a larger version of the image so you can inspect it better.

**P.S.** I couldn't decide whether to post this on meta or here. On the one hand, the question is about this website, so it should be asked on meta. On the other hand, it is a mathematical question, so it also belongs here. Please, move the question to meta if you deem it fit. As an alternative, we can split this question and post one half on meta and leave the other one here.

Comment: @hardmath I have reported to a moderator that my question is a duplicate of one on meta.

Comment: @hardmath don't get me wrong: the question on meta you mentioned _does_ answer mine exhaustively. The image I'm interested in is just a Penrose triangle in disguise. This little piece of information is a gateway to all kinds of interesting mathematics-related stuff.